# moving elements inside a container using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, containers

I have an issue with a project I'm working on, I'm holding buttons inside a container, whenever I try to move them in css the buttons will disappear, and setting a top or right relative value of the container css will move the entire website, what I'm trying to achieve is have all the buttons lined up on the right side, I've included a small sample of the code which is my current work, and a link to the site so you can see the result.

I believe the issue might be with the size of the canvas, but increasing the size of the canvas stretches all the images to fit it, and I'm still unable to move them using the css. Thank you for any help you can provide.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="webgl"></div>
        <input type="image" id="intro" src="images/icon-intro.png"/>
        <input type="image" id="avatar" src="images/icon-avatar.png"/>
        <input type="image" id="news" src="images/icon-news.png"/>
        <input type="image" id="play" src="images/icon-play.png"/>
        <input type="image" id="stop" src="images/icon-stop.png"/>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
#intro,
#intro {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#intro {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

A link to the site that has the issue:

http://playground.eca.ed.ac.uk/~s1572393/

Thanks again for any help or explanations.

Comment: You need to learn [CSS positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/). After you go through the tutorial, if you still need help, rewrite your question asking about what you didn't understand or have trouble applying.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll go through it now and try and solve the issue, great resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the recourse in the question comments I was able to solve the issue.

I removed the container and refactored the css for the input elements to the following:

```
#intro {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 30px; 
  z-index: 10; 
}
```